# How can I change the background color of the navigation bar in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I would like to change the background color of the navigation bar. But what am I doing wrong that the colors look so different?

[image]

My code:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .red

return VStack(spacing: 0) {
    Text("Test")
        .padding(.top, 9.5)
        .padding(.bottom, 8)
        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(Color.red)
        .font(.footnote)
    NavigationView {
        Text("Hello")
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Hi"), displayMode: .inline)
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
With [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58427754/3088606), it gets better but there is still a difference in color.
[image]

My code now:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Text("Test")
                .padding(.top, 9.5)
                .padding(.bottom, 8)
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(Color("red")) // Now I use a color set
                .font(.footnote)
            NavigationView {
                Text("Hello")
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Hi"), displayMode: .inline)
                .background(NavigationConfigurator { nc in
                    nc.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(named: "red") // Now I use a color set
                })
            }
        }
    }
}

struct NavigationConfigurator: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    var configure: (UINavigationController) -> Void = { _ in }

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<NavigationConfigurator>) -> UIViewController {
        UIViewController()
    }
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<NavigationConfigurator>) {
        if let nc = uiViewController.navigationController {
            self.configure(nc)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: https://www.morningswiftui.com/blog/customizing-navigation-bar-ios13

Comment: Also, you are using both `background(Color("red"))` and `UIColor(named: "red")`.

Comment: I think that makes no difference because I use the same [color set](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/supporting_dark_mode_in_your_interface/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## iOS 16

You can set any color directly on toolbar items like the navigation bar with the following modifier:

```
.toolbarBackground(.red, in: .navigationBar)
```

[image: Demo]

---

## iOS 15 and below

The issue is with the `UINavigationBar`'s `backgroundImage`. You should set it to an empty `UIImage` like:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    init() { 
        UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .red // Or any other color
        UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ,,,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you specify the `displayMode: .inline` parameter, the color underneath the navigation bar (in this case, white) gets blended into the nav bar's color, leaving you with this pinkish color. You will get full red if its a large title style.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58427754/3088606) is a better way of setting the navigation bar color, and will work even with the `.inline` style.

Finally, note that `Color.red` is actually the same as `UIColor.systemRed`. If you use `UIColor.red`, you'll notice a difference in Dark Mode.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, it does not really work for me, but maybe I misunderstood something. I've also added a screenshot to the question to show what has changed with this solution.